# Asset validation failed ,agorartc.framework

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, testflight, agora

We are getting this error while quploading xcode ipa to test flight

Asset validation failed (90125) The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker. (ID: 5f7fa552-dd48-4ae8-832e-d6749457ae4e)

Asset validation failed (90087) Unsupported Architectures. The executable for DLF.app/Frameworks/AgoraRtcWrapper.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'. (ID: af02e713-062c-453d-8c58-b5c28c5d1ba6)

Iam trying to upload ios build to testfilght but got error from agorartc.framework